# Difference/Intersection not reflecting in stl export

Tags: modifiers, stl

[image: Blender rendered Image]

[image: Exported stl Image]

Why are the objects taken for difference and intersection shown in stl file even though I have not selected them while exporting.

Comment: Just to confirm, Selection Only is checked in export, yes?

Comment: Need to apply bools?